# linking updateview form with template form in django

Tags: django, django-views

I want to have CreateView and UpdateView form on the same page but update form is displayed only when edit button is pressed which is also on the same page 
but the problem is when edit button is pressed it is redirected to update view(ie same page) if the URL of updateView is linked to the button and if I don't link the updateView to the button then the form is not auto-filed to be update. what is its solution?

```
class stock_add_view(CreateView):
    model = part_stock
    fields = ['part_id','entry_date','supplier','amount','remaining']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('parts:part_list')

class stock_update_view(UpdateView):
    model = part_stock
    fields = ['part_id','entry_date','supplier','amount','remaining']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('parts:part_list')
    template_name = 'part_detail.html'
```

> URL pattern

```
   url(r'^add_stock$',views.stock_add_view.as_view(),name='stock_add_view'),
url(r'^update_stock/(?P<pk>\d+)/$',views.stock_update_view.as_view(),name='stock_update_view'),
```

> Template: part_detail.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('.edit_btn').on('click',pop_up);
    function pop_up() {
        alert("hi")
        $('#update_form').show();
    }
})
</script>
<div>//add form
<form method="post" action="{% url 'parts:stock_add_view'%}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit">
</form>
</div>
<div style="display: none;" id="update_form">//update form
<form method="post" action="{% url 'parts:stock_update_view' stock.id%}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit">
</form>
</div>
//edit button
<a href=""> <button type="button" class="edit_btn" data-id="{{ stock.id }}">Edit</button></a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using the same fields for both forms, instead of two Class based Views , just use one that extends a FormView and use the update_or_create method

```
class stock_add_view(FormView):
    model = part_stock
    template_name = 'part_detail.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('parts:part_list') 

    def form_valid(self, form):
        part_stock.objects.update_or_create(
            'part_id': form.cleaned_data["part_id"]
            defaults={
                'entry_date': form.cleaned_data["entry_date"],
                'supplier': form.cleaned_data["supplier"],
                'amount': form.cleaned_data['amount'],  
                'remaining':form.cleaned_data['remainig'],  
            }
        )
        return render(self.request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

This means that django will look for an object with id=part_id,if it exists, it will be updated else it will be created, with data in the default's dict